# Aiohttp web server as virtualhost?

Tags: aiohttp

It is necessary to add to the aiohttp Web server to support multiple domains. Possible routes to bind to domains? I would be grateful for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aiohttp is an HTTP client/server **library** for python, and not a standalone product.  Applications built with aiohttp should probably be served behind a reverse proxy (such as nginx) that easily handles configuration options such as multiple domains/virtualhosts and much much more. Refer to aiohttp's [deployment documentation](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html) for more info.